# How to manage dynamically generated variables in Assembly

Tags: assembly, jit

Along the lines of [How v8 JIT compiler manages dynamically changing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992545/how-v8-jit-compiler-manages-dynamically-changing-variables), wondering how you would go about creating dynamically generated variables in assembly. Not necessarily looking for example assembly code. More looking for a general high-level description of how you would define and then update a variable a low-level language dealing directly with memory addresses, such as assembly. Wondering if somehow the idea of symbol tables fits in here.

For example, in JavaScript you can create a variable such as this:

```
var a = []

function b() {
  var c = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  a.push(c)
  d()
}

function d() {
  var e = [ 4, 5, 6 ]
  var c = a[0]
  c.push(e)
}

b()
```

Wondering how that sort of thing would look in assembly.

Comment: There isn't a one to one mapping between Javascript commands and assembly commands. The storage of local variables isn't done through a single assembly instruction, but via management of a fairly complex data structure. This is answered in a question on the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800463/how-variables-are-allocated-memory-in-javascript) site.

Comment: That link is a helpful resource, which also links to http://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs491/three-imp.pdf which helps too. But I am looking for a bit more low-level. JavaScript is implemented in C in v8 at least which already has a lot of features to deal with variables. That link describes binding objects, but I wonder how those objects would look in assembly, because they themselves are C objects defined by variables :[ The JS is just an example, doesn't need to be mapped from that JS example to assembly, just looking for assembly in general.

Comment: Well at the assembly level it's going to be registers, blocks of memory, pointers to blocks of memory, pointers to arrays of pointers to memory, etc. However the assembly for the Javascript code managing local variables would  be several dozen pages, not something easily presented here. Have you looked at how local variables are managed in 'simpler' languages using a stack?

Comment: I have seen how assembly uses the stack to deal with function input, but I haven't seen how it has pointers to arrays of pointers to memory, I would like to basically see that.

Comment: In the end, this is about data structures. And there's not a tremendous difference between C and assembly in this respect. Both have weak/no typing, no GC, and unrestricted pointers. So how would you express the above code in C? You can then plug the code into the Godbolt compiler explorer and see corresponding assembly. Note that “dynamically generated variable” is a bit vague – do you mean variable names that only spring into existence at runtime (e.g. JS `with` statement), or objects that are allocated at runtime?

Comment: In assembly, if you need a new local variable (as in your `c` or `e`) you just use a CPU register.  The only thing is you have to make sure the value currently in the register is not being otherwise used for something else.  You keep track of that outside of the assembly code, e.g. in comments or in your head, or in a symbol table if you are a code generator.  That metadata (what's where) doesn't make it into actual machine code itself except as instructions using registers.

Comment: (If you are out of registers, you can allocate some stack space.)  If you want a global variable (as in your `a`) you reserve some storage in the .data or .bss section and give it a label that you can use to reference it.